# Application closes immediately

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

The application does not start when I try to debug. The last changes I made are to a graph, if in doubt I removed it from both xaml code and c # but the error persists, so the problem is something else.

I was making some changes to the '`DiaryPage`' page while trying to debug the application immediately stops in the `MainPage`, therefore not even arriving at the aforementioned page. There are no exceptions in `mainPage`. From what I understand, it crashes when it has to access an ftp space.

```
WebClient clientw = new WebClient();
clientw.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxxx");
string Frasi = "ftp://epiz_27@ftpupload.net/htdocs/word1.json";
```

When it gets to read this last line of code, it crashes and closes.

```
string contents = await clientw.DownloadStringTaskAsync(Frasi);
```

This is the log:

> > ## Native Crash Reporting
> > ================================================================= Got a SEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
> > error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
> > application.
> >
> > No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
> >
> > =================================================================   Basic Fault Address Reporting
> > ================================================================= Memory around native instruction pointer (0x78535d4414):0x78535d4404
> > 30 00 a0 f2 f1 03 00 91 31 02 10 cb 3f 02 00 91  0.......1...?...
> > 0x78535d4414  fd 7b 00 a9 fd 03 00 91 a0 0b 00 f9 10 35 9b d2
> > .{...........5.. 0x78535d4424  90 1a a9 f2 10 0f c0 f2 b0 0f 00 f9 10
> > 00 84 d2  ................ 0x78535d4434  50 f7 b2 f2 10 0f c0 f2 b0 13
> > 00 f9 1e 9d 8d d2  P...............
> >
> > ===================================================04-06 23:12:25.794 F/libc    (17288): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2
> > (SEGV_ACCERR),
> > fault addr 0x7ff13dad50 in tid 17288 (mpanyname.myapp), pid 17288
> > (mpanyname.myapp)
> >
> > ==============  Managed Stacktrace:
> > =================================================================     at MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x00014>     at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.ctor <0x008f3>    at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:InitializeComponent <0x01e97>      at
> > MyApp.Pagine.DiaryPage:.c tor <0x008f3>   at MyApp.TabPage:.ctor <0x00077>    at MyApp.App:.ctor <0x0057f>    at
> > MyApp.Droid.MainActivity:OnCreate <0x0018b>     at
> > Android.App.Activity:n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ <0x000d3>       at
> > Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter:8 <0x000cf>    at
> > Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter:8 <0x000eb>

```
04-06 23:37:20.639 D/Mono    (19321): Requesting loading reference 1 (of 2) of Java.Interop.dll
04-06 23:37:20.639 D/Mono    (19321): Loading reference 1 of Java.Interop.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
04-06 23:37:20.639 D/Mono    (19321): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x78a523dc00] -> System.Core[0x78a5410900]: 7
```

The errors seem to indicate `DiaryPage` but in reality the application crashes in `MainPage`

**UPDATE:**
I tried to completely delete the method in which that code is contained but the app keeps crashing

Comment: The crashes seems to be in `DiaryPage's constructor`. Did you put a breaking point before `InitializeComponent()` call to see if it reaches that page? It could also be that `MyApp.TabPage` shown in the stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like its in an infinite loop. As if DiaryPage xaml or constructor code contains a sub-object that is also a DiaryPage. Which obviously won't work. (If you don't see anything in your xaml or C# that explains this, then something corrupted in build? Delete any bin and obj folders, to make sure the project is completely clean. Rebuild.)

Comment: *"The errors seem to indicate DiaryPage but in reality the application crashes in MainPage"* - the stack trace tells us that a DiaryPage gets constructed during Android Activity.OnCreate: the app creates a TabPage, which contains a DiaryPage. The problem happens during the construction of DiaryPage. To prove this, remove DiaryPage from TabPage. Problem won't happen. Therefore, must fix something in DiaryPage's xaml, or its constructor code.

Comment: I went by trial and error and finally solved it. Inside the DiaryPage, in XAML, I had inserted this <ContentPage.BindingContext>
         <local: DiaryPage />
     </ContentPage.BindingContext>